# Is it a requirement that jurors of a state prosecution be residents of the state that brought the legal proceedings?

Tags: jury

Would a jury of your peers preclude jury members of neighboring states from deciding on your guilt? Is there any geographical consideration of who and what is considered your peers? I'm asking specifically for state cases, I'm assuming on a federal case they could probably get jurors from all over.

Answer (score 2):

For federal prosecutions, the Sixth Amendment gives defendants a right to trial “by an impartial jury of the State and district wherein the crime shall have been committed.” This hasn’t been applied to the states, but I believe every state in fact requires jurors be at least residents of that state (states sometimes go farther and require that jurors be from the same county).